# Time duration calculation using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Is it possible to do the below `c#` logic in `javascript` or `jquery`, The code converts duration between two dates int hours,minutes and seconds.the duration 20/01/2017 00:00:00 to 20/01/2017 02:20:30 will be 26:20:30
This about converting to **hh:mm:ss** format hours can go beyond 24, if minutes are more than 59 it should add to hours and seconds more than 59 should add to hours.

```
public static string ToTimeFormat(bool includeSeconds = false)
{
    var startDate = DateTime.parse("20/01/2017 00:00:00";
    var endDate = DateTime.parse("20/01/2017 02:20:30");
    var ts = endDate - startDate;
    var totalDaysToHours = ts.Days * 24;

    return string.Format("{0}:{1}", (ts.Hours + totalDaysToHours).ToString("0"), 
                                     ts.Minutes.ToString("D2")) 
                                     + (includeSeconds ? ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString("D2") : string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Get the ticks from both dates then do the subtraction. The ticks can be converted to any unit you choose (days, minutes, seconds). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: This not duplicate, This is to convert date into different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `moment.js` from here [moment.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js) and below is the code

```
var startDate  = "01/02/2016 00:00:00"; //MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format
var endDate = "01/03/2016 01:30:30"; //MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format
var diff = moment.duration(moment(endDate).diff(moment(startDate)));
var formatedData=[diff.asHours().toFixed(0), diff.minutes(), diff.seconds()].join(':');
```

so your output will be like

```
26:30:30
```

**UPDATE**

```
var startDate  = "01/02/2016 00:00:00".split(/\//);
startDate= [ startDate[1], startDate[0], startDate[2] ].join('/'); // DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY
var endDate = "01/03/2016 01:30:30".split(/\//);
endDate = [ endDate[1], endDate[0], endDate[2] ].join('/'); // DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY
var diff = moment.duration(moment(endDate).diff(moment(startDate)));
var formatedData=[diff.asHours().toFixed(0), diff.minutes(),diff.seconds()].join(':');
```

Comment: How can I convert date to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS      'var formattedStartdt = moment(new Date(txtStartDate.value)).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                                var formattedEnddt = moment(new Date(txtEndDate.value)).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");


                                var diff = moment.duration(moment(formattedEnddt).diff(moment(formattedStartdt)));'